# Align widget in bottom navigation covers body

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Scaffold with the following architecture, and the body is being covered by the bottom navigation. Everything works fine if I comment the navigation.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppAppBar(title: this.title),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: this.pageProvider.horizontalPadding,
                    vertical: 25),
                child: this.body,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AppNavigation(),
    );
```

This is the implementation of the AppNavigation widget:

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            height: 64,
            child: BottomNavigation(),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            height: 80,
            child: WorkoutButton(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

This is the body, regardless of what widget I use:
[image: Bug]

In case it is not clear enough, the body does not have almost height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don’t you use a `BottomNavigationBar` widget instead of a `Stack`?

Anyway, that happens because your `Stack` is unconstrained, thus, using all the available space. Give it some constrains (E.g., by wrapping it in a `ConstrainedBox` with some height constraint).

```
ConstrainedBox(
     constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 150.0),
     child: Stack( ...
     )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Miguel! It worked perfectly! I decided not to go with the BottomNavigationBar because I wanted to create my own layout. With your help, everything looks great :D